# BCC For drupal mail function

Tags: emails

I am using Drupal 7 and focused to work with email option. I am using the [Forward](http://drupal.org/project/forward) module. How can I add the BCC field in the [drupal_mail](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7)() function.

my default function having,

```
drupal_mail('forward', 'forward_page', trim($to), language_default(), $params, $params['from']);
```

Answer (score 28):

Everything you need is in the email message headers array.

```
$params['headers'] = array(
    'Bcc' => 'bcc_email@example.com',
    'Cc' => 'cc_email@example.com',
);
```

Here is an example implementation of [drupal_mail](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7)() with bcc headers included.

```
$params = array(
    'body' => $body,
    'subject' => $subject,
    'headers' => array(
        'Bcc' => $header_bcc,
        'Cc' => $header_cc
    )
);

$email = drupal_mail('ModuleName', 'message_key', $to, LANGUAGE_NONE, $params, $from, true);
```

Using [hook_mail](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7)() you need to add (thank you @[clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive)):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function ModuleName_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
    switch ($key) {
        case 'message_key':
            $message['headers'] += $params['headers'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the hook mail alter for changing or adding altered to, cc and bcc mail ids, see the example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter().
 */
function hook_mail_alter(&$message) {
  $message['to'] = 'mail@gmail.com';
  $message['headers']['Bcc'] = 'Your mail ids goes here with comma seperation';
  $message['headers']['Cc'] = 'Your mail ids goes here with comma seperation';
}
```

Also you can use bcc and cc mail ids in the $params array of drupal_mail():

```
$params = array(
  'body' => $body,
  'subject' => 'Your Subject',
  'headers' => array(
    'Cc' => 'Your mail ids goes here with comma seperation',
    'Bcc' => 'Your mail ids goes here with comma seperation',
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a module for that: If you want to get a bcc of all mails that drupal sends check out the [BCC Module](https://drupal.org/project/bcc).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$message['headers']['Bcc'] = 'email@address.com';
```

Answer (score 1):

In `hook_mail_alter()` use `$message['params']['headers']['Bcc'] = 'yourmail@gmail.com';`.