# identify author of an entity

Tags: 8, emails

Using Drupal 8 and hooks, I am able to send an email to the current user, thanks to [How to send mail programmatically in Drupal 8](https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/how-to-send-mail-programmatically-drupal-8)
and
[BCC For drupal mail function](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41329/bcc-for-drupal-mail-function/224191).

So, I define my message in `hook_entity_update()` and send it in `hook_mail()`.

I am trying to send emails in the following case.

1. user U1 consult a node created by user U2 (the aim is to permit to U1 to give his impression to U2 thanks to a select field). When U1 gave his impression, content is registered.
2. I need to send a email to U2 (the node author), but since he isn't the current user, I cannot use `\Drupal::currentUser()`.

In `hook_entity_update()`, how can I identify the author of the current entity, knowing that "author" is not provided by `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface`?

Is there a specific service?

Comment: You would need to look up the revision of the content and its author. Please see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/116334/preferred-way-of-loading-a-specific-entity-revision, that should give you some direction.

Comment: You most likely won't need revision, I guess your entity is also implementing [Drupal/Core/Entity/FieldableEntityInterface.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21FieldableEntityInterface.php/interface/FieldableEntityInterface/8.2.x), which means you can get the author id with `$entity->get('uid')->value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik, there's no requirement that a Content Entity **must** store the id of the user who created/edited it. However, many entity types do use a common method to store the owner information - Drupal core's *user* module provides an [EntityOwnerTrait](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21EntityOwnerTrait.php/trait/EntityOwnerTrait/8.7.x) that many entity types use. (At least Node, Media, etc, all use this trait.)

For example, if you're looking for the owner of an entity that uses this trait, you can use the [`getOwner()` method](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21EntityOwnerTrait.php/function/EntityOwnerTrait%3A%3AgetOwner/8.7.x) like:

```
$owner_user_object = $entity->getOwner();
```

---

It's unclear if user *U2*, in your example, would be the owner of the entity or just the author of a particular revision. If your entity is storing revision information, and the entity extends [EditorialContentEntityBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EditorialContentEntityBase.php/class/EditorialContentEntityBase/8.4.x) (Note that they probably do. Node, Media, etc, all extend this base class) then it's also possible to load the author of a particular revision.

First, load the revision. See @baikho's comment pointing to [Preferred way of loading a specific entity revision](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/116334/preferred-way-of-loading-a-specific-entity-revision).

```
$entity_revision = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('MY_ENTITY_EYPE')
  ->loadRevision($MY_REVISION_ID);
```

Once you'd loaded the revision, you can get the author of that revision with the [`getRevisionUser()` method](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21RevisionLogEntityTrait.php/function/RevisionLogEntityTrait%3A%3AgetRevisionUser/8.4.x) like:

```
$revision_user_object = $entity_revision->getRevisionUser()
```

Answer (score 2):

`EntityInterface` doesn't have any method for getting the user who created an entity because not all the entities have the concept of owner. For example, the User entity is one of those entities.

The entities for which is defined an owner implement [`EntityOwnerInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21EntityOwnerInterface.php/interface/EntityOwnerInterface/8.9.x).

> An owner is someone who has primary control over an entity, similar to owners in Unix file system access. This may or may not be the entity's original author. The owner may also have less permissions than other users, such as administrators.

If you are implementing `hook_entity_update()` for a generic entity and you want to check if it has an owner, you should use code similar to the following one.

```php
use \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use \Drupal\user\EntityOwnerInterface;

function hook_entity_update(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity instanceof EntityOwnerInterface) {
    // The entity has an owner (a.k.a. an author).
    $author_id = $entity->getOwnerId();
    $autor = $entity->getOwner();
  }
}
```

If the entity implements [`RevisionLogInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21RevisionLogInterface.php/interface/RevisionLogInterface/8.9.x) (which means it supports revisions, and it usually extends  [`RevisionableContentEntityBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21RevisionableContentEntityBase.php/class/RevisionableContentEntityBase/8.9.x)), then it also defines a revision author, returned from `getRevisionUser()`.